# How to automatically update index page with route "/" using different render parameters every 5 minutes or so with node.js?

Tags: node.js, ejs

How do I automate page rendering with different render parameters every 5 minutes or so? Is it possible to make that I could be sitting at index page and the specified fields would be updated at specified intervals?

Currently I only managed to display that information by using different routes "/" and "labs" and by manually accessing them. The data that I'm trying to change with each GET is between uniTimes[0].lectures and uniTimes[1].labs, and also with each render I'm changing data in blockHeights and verticalPosition variables.

**Get request which points to the index page:**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {

// Lectures/Lab Works times object array

  var uniTimes = [
    {
      lectures: [
        {
          title: "Information System Security",
          classroom: "503a.",
          start: "1995-12-17T08:00:00",
          end: "1995-12-17T09:15:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Project Management",
          classroom: "117a.",
          start: "1995-12-17T08:30:00",
          end: "1995-12-17T09:30:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Audiovisual Art",
          classroom: "228a.",
          start: "1995-12-17T09:45:00",
          end: "1995-12-17T12:00:00"
        } 
      ]
    },
    {
      labs: [
        {
          title: "Graphic Design",
          classroom: "505a.",
          start: "1995-12-17T09:15:00",
          end: "1995-12-17T10:15:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Special Effects",
          classroom: "228a.",
          start: "1995-12-17T11:30:00",
          end: "1995-12-17T12:00:00"
        },
        {
          title: "Robotics",
          classroom: "513a.",
          start: "1995-12-17T08:45:00",
          end: "1995-12-17T09:30:00"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]

  //Displayed lecture/lab work block size
  var blockHeights = ["250px", "200px", "450px"];

  //Displayed lecture/lab work block position
  var verticalPosition = ["0px", "100px", "350px"];

  res.render('index', { title: 'Express Application', subTitle: 'Student Timetables Display', uniTimes: uniTimes[0].lectures, blockHeights: blockHeights, verticalPosition: verticalPosition });

});
```

**Index Ejs page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= subTitle %></p>
    <a href="/admin">Go to admin panel</a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <% for(var i = 0; i < uniTimes.length; i++) { %>
      <div style="float:left; width: 150px; margin-right: 25px; height: <%= blockHeights[i] %>; background-color: red; margin-top: <%= verticalPosition[i] %>">
        <h3><%= uniTimes[i].title %></h3>
        <h4><%= uniTimes[i].classroom %></h4>
        <h4><%= uniTimes[i].start %></h4>
        <h4><%= uniTimes[i].end %></h4>
      </div>
    <% } %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your gonna need to use ur UI to re-render.
send request every X mins and re-render what ever you want.

Comment: I don't think requests are necessary--just send all the data to the frontend and use `setInterval` to check the time every 5 minutes and display the correct class(es) that match the current time range. It's not entirely clear what OP is looking for, though, so I don't feel confident in constructing an answer beyond that. More clarification of exact result would be helpful.

Comment: Isn't it a problem of architecture ? Have you take a look at websockets ? (like socket.io for real-time update)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to switch between indexes on fetched data in ejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56043977/how-to-switch-between-indexes-on-fetched-data-in-ejs)